# Opscenter is giving 'Duplicate: The keypair 'OpsCenterProvisioningKeyPair' already exists' on trying to create another cluster in same region

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

OpsCenter 5.2.4 is giving following on trying to create another cluster in same region, obviously it already has a keypair but its trying to recreate.

Keypair Creation failed: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'OpsCenterProvisioningKeyPair' already exists

Is it possible to customise the keypair name to reuse?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter developer here. If you're using OpsCenter for provisioning, you REALLY want to upgrade to 6.0.5 and use the newish Lifecycle Manager feature instead of the provisioning feature in OpsCenter 5.2.x. The legacy provisioning feature was both unreliable and difficult to debug. LCM is a giant step forward.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Glad my questioned is noticed by just right person. Am on cassandra 2.1.13 and I have data snapshot from production taken from OpsCenter 5.2.4, as a result I was trying to get same version so that restore is not a problem. Do you think 6.0.5 won't have compatibility issues?

Comment: I work mainly on the provisioning features and don't know the answer to that off the top of my head. I've pinged in our private chatroom to have someone with backup expertise have a look at this question to speak to cross-version restore compatibility. My expectation is that it will work, but in the worst case, you can always stand up a second copy of opscenter 6.0.5 to do the install (maybe a tarball install in your homedir on the same machine if you don't have a second machine handy) and then restore the backup using OpsCenter 5.2.4. I doubt that's necessary, though.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work. You should be good to go. It's worth mentioning that if you ever upgrade cassandra versions,  you'd most likely need to run sstableupgrade on the sstables from the snapshot from a prior version of Cassandra.